# How does a falling rock minimize action?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, boundary-conditions, action

Consider a single two dimensional system with a rock that is influenced by gravity. The Action of this system is defined as $\int_0^\infty [T(\dot x(t))-V(x(t))]dt$, where $T$ is the kinetic and $V$ is the potential energy.

Intuitively, in order to minimize action, one wants low average kinetic energy and high average potential energy over time. However, if I place a rock in the air, what happens is, it falls down, increasing its kinetic energy and decreasing its potential energy. Shouldn't it move UPWARD in order to minimize action?

Answer (score 2):

In a dynamical [variational principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_principle) like the [principle of stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), it is necessary to impose boundary conditions (BCs). Without BCs, the action is not bounded from below nor from above, cf. OP's observations. With appropriate BCs, e.g Dirichlet BCs $$x(t_i)~=~x_i\quad\text{and}\quad x(t_f)~=~x_f,$$ one can determine the stationary path(s) via the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).

Comment: So in this case, the BC would be the initial position and velocity, and the final position and velocity of the rock, right? How do we derive that velocity, without solving the dynamics in the first place?

Comment: It seems that you are talking about initial conditions (ICs), which are not appropriate for variational problems.

Comment: I meant the initial AND final conditions.

Comment: Good. Note that if you impose too many BCs, there are typically no solutions.

Comment: 1. Are you implying that there are too many BC's if I assume both a final and initial position and velocity? 2. Either way I'm confused, since if we indeed assume both initial AND final conditions, then I don't know how to derive the final conditions in the first place without already having solved the problem, but if we don't assume the final condition then I don't know how to prevent the system from blowing up like I described.

Comment: 1. Yes, in $d$ dimensions, you need precisely $2d$ BCs. 2. The BCs are not derived; they are assumed.

Comment: I see, so the only way to make it work is to assume the initial and final position at t=0 and t=T, and then the velocities will follow from this.

Comment: Actually, some mixed combinations of [BCs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110506/11127) are also possible.